# Using ctx in koa middlware

Tags: node.js, middleware, koa, ctx

I have a koa middleware that I am using like this:

`.use(signS3())`

What I want to do now is use the `ctx` object from koa in the config object from signS3(). I would like to do something like this:

`.use((ctx, next) => signS3({ keyPrefix: ctx.host })(ctx, next))`

But this doesn't work. I am thinking I have the syntax wrong, would appreciate any input on how to do this.

Comment: Should work fine. How do you detect that this is not working, and what is inside `signS3` function?

Comment: @OlesSavluk Don't know exactly how it is breaking, but the first one works and the second one does not. `signS3` is a koa middleware https://github.com/ktonon/koa-s3-sign-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using middleware written for `koa@1` which uses generators instead of `async/await`.  You should have noticed this warning when running your application:

> koa deprecated Support for generators will be removed in v3. See the documentation for examples of how to convert old middleware https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/migration.md

In order to use this middleware in `koa@2` you need to convert it, manually or using [koa-convert](https://github.com/koajs/convert). For example:

```js
const convert = require('koa-convert');

app.use(
  (ctx, next) => convert(
    signS3({
      bucket: 'MyBucket',
      keyPrefix: ctx.host,
    })
  )(ctx, next)
);
```

Also take a look at official documentation about [Using v1.x Middleware in v2.x](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/migration.md#using-v1x-middleware-in-v2x)